# Map the user's request to the corresponding page

Tags: c#

How can I map the user's request to the corresponding page? For example: user requests `http://127.0.0.1:8090/Test/Login?username=1&password=2`, to read the `/Test/Login.index` file in the server directory. When the user requests: `http://127.0.0.1:8090/Test/Register?Username=1&amp;password=2` (Registration)
`http://127.0.0.1:8090/Test/Login?Username=1&amp;password=2` (login)
When the request comes, how to deal with? This is how I deal with the following code:

```
if (URL.Equals("/Test/Login.html"))
{
    UM.UserName = request.Params["username"];
    UM.Password = request.Params["password"];
    jsons = dbuserdata.Login(UM.UserName,UM.Password );
    Console.WriteLine("返回的json数据：{0}",jsons);
}
else if (URL.Equals("/Test/Register.html"))
{
    UM.UserName = request.Params["username"];
    UM.Password = request.Params["password"];
    jsons = dbuserdata.Register(UM.UserName,UM.Password );
    Console.WriteLine("返回的json数据：{0}",jsons);
}
```

If there are hundreds of requests, I would have to write hundreds of if/else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code to extract the common pieces, then use a `switch` statement:

```
UM.UserName = request.Params["username"];
UM.Password = request.Params["password"];

switch(URL)
{
    case "/Test/Login.html":
        jsons = dbuserdata.Login(UM.UserName,UM.Password );
        Console.WriteLine("返回的json数据：{0}",jsons);
        break;
    case "/Test/Register.html":
        jsons = dbuserdata.Register(UM.UserName,UM.Password );
        Console.WriteLine("返回的json数据：{0}",jsons);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("unknown/unhandled");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you may not notice that the data returned by the different links is different. This method is feasible, but if there are a lot of links, the program becomes huge

Comment: My example program, a call is the registration method, one is the login method，Or so, when there are a lot of requests, how do I map to the appropriate page, read the data and return to the client.

Comment: My apologies, I do see it now.  I'll edit the method, but I'm sure it's now what you're looking for.